# How to save objects from an array of objects individually in Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I try to send to my Redux state an array of objects and I try to save it in my state.

Redux State:

```
savedEvents: [],
```

My array of elements I try to send looks like: `[{1},{2}]`

My dispatch method :

```
case 'events/setNewEvent': 
            return { ...state, savedEvents: [...state.savedEvents, action.payload] };
```

If I try to use this 'case', my 'savedEvents' will look like `[[{1},{2}]]` ant not like `[{1},{2}]`. Both will be on index 0.

What I have to change in my code to be saved individually, and not together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to spread the new events in with the `...` operator:

```
return { ...state, savedEvents: [...state.savedEvents, ...action.payload] };
```